# jQuery tabs not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to implement jQuery tabs to replace AJAX tab container. I've followed the code from the [jquery website](http://jquery.com) but my tabs aren't showing up. It just loads the entire page full of data with no tabs. And firebug tells me the following error:

`$("#tabs").tabs is not a function`

`$("#tabs").tabs();`

I've got references to all the files needed:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

And I've got the function specified as follows:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#tabs").tabs();
     });

  </script>
```

The code for the tabs are as follows:

```
div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-1"><span>Patient Information</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2"><span>Medical History 1 of 3</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3"><span>Medical History 2 of 3</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-4"><span>Medical History 3 of 3</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-5"><span>Scheduler</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-6"><span>Care Plan</span></a></li>
    </ul> 
<div id="tab-1">
</div>
**Repeats for all tabs through tab-6**
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Since the .tabs() function isn't working the page is just loading like so -[image: No Tabs]

Comment: It sounds like jquery UI is failing to load. Are sure the js file is actually loading. Check the firebug net tab if you have firebug (which you should).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code works just fine. The only thing you're missing is the CSS for the tabs - http://jsfiddle.net/8JX4A/

Comment: @AlxVallejo from the jQuery UI demo site

Answer (score 7):

If you have another jQuery element in the same page maybe you have conflicts. I have the same problem, try with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();     
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#tabs").tabs();
 });
```

Then only change `i:; jQuery.noConflict();` before each jQuery element.

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict();` this answered my problem.

Comment: I still don't understand why, but this solved my issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to link the CSS file:
http://jsfiddle.net/fJaBa/

Comment: The location is in the first line of the upper left panel of the jsfiddle linked.

Answer (score 2):

Try loading scripts in this sequence

```
<script src="../../jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
```

Comment: The sequence definitely mattered for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.tabs = function() {
    var selector = this;

    this.each(function() {
        var obj = $(this); 

        $(obj.attr('href')).hide();

        $(obj).click(function() {
            $(selector).removeClass('active');

            $(selector).each(function(i, element) {
                $($(element).attr('href')).hide();
            });

            $(this).addClass('active');

            $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn();

            return false;
        });
    });

    $(this).show();

    $(this).first().click();
};
```

[Live Demo Here](http://livetheme.in/Example/tabs)

Answer (score 0):

Not a jquery expert but I do know you will need some css to make the tabs work correctly. since they will need to be positioned relative. Also check out this [jquery tabs tutorial](http://yensdesign.com/2008/12/create-a-smooth-tabbed-menu-in-jquery/) to compare your code.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `1.8` alias to the jQuery UI lib working? Have you tried using a specific full version, like `1.8.16` instead? Can you look at the page once it's loaded and see if jQuery and/or jQuery UI were actually pulled in successfully?