# EasyTabs + Slider script - Slider won't initialize

Tags: javascript

I'm using EasyTabs (http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs) to structure my website. I'd like to add a slider script to operate within one of the tabs that's not initially visible. The slider script won't activate when the tab is selected.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.ba-hashchange.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.easytabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
```

This starts the EasyTabs script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#tab-container').easytabs();
});
</script>
```

This starts the Slider script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#slides').slidesjs({
    width: 1000,
    height: 444,
    navigation: false,
    play: {
        interval: 2000,
        auto: true
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

All of that is in the header.

```
</head>
```

How can I get that Slider script to initialize upon clicking on the EasyTabs tab that contains it? Thanks!

Comment: Recommend you use developer tools in your browser to see what sort of script error your getting...

Comment: I'm not getting any errors that I can see, maybe this will help:

This a direct link to the tab that contains the Slider:
http://www.kcchartaire.com/v4/aboutus.html#tabs1-slide
As you see, it works if you get a direct link to that tab.

But users will arrive to the initial page with the Slider tab hidden. Once you click on the Slider tab (the last one) you will see the slideshow doesnt show up:
http://www.kcchartaire.com/v4/aboutus.html

Answer (score 0):

In [jQuery tabs not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022897/jquery-tabs-not-working) it was suggested to place jQuery.noConflict(); right before the document ready function.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem with the Bootstrap framework and my image slider, the slider loads its script before the tab and its content is active, causing a not quite working slider. Is there an Event Handler of some sort to load the Script just as the Tab is open ?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript" defer>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.slider').bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 214,
            minSlides: 1,
            maxSlides: 3,
            moveSlides: 1,
            slideMargin: 20
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Picture of how it looks after load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crn6j.jpg)

[Picture of how it looks when I open the Console, forcing the script to reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdUwh.jpg)

All Scripts are at the end of the body, after all html content